# What documents required in order to pass by motorcycle from Turkey to Northern Iraq?

Tags: paperwork, motorcycles, iraqi-kurdistan, spanish-citizens

For example, a Spanish citizen wants to go from Spain to India overland by motorcycle via France, Italy, Slovenia, Croatia, Serbia, Bulgaria, turkey (crossing from Europe to Asia is made via the first Bosporus bridge in Istanbul), Iraq, Iran and Pakistan. The motorcycle is a Suzuki V-Strom DL650 with Spanish registration number plates in the back.

So, I want to know what documents are required alongside the Spanish passport for crossing from Turkey to Northern Iraq (the safest zone of the country)?

Comment: That might be the safest part of Iraq, but that's one of the more dangerous parts of Turkey.

Comment: "Safest" doesn't imply "safe."

Comment: Note that as of May, the border crossing from Turkey to Iraq had a low quota, so presumably several days' wait. http://rudaw.net/english/middleeast/turkey/050120161

Comment: I repeat [comments](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79280/sweden-to-japan-by-road#comment178703_79280) made [on your other questions](http://travel.stackexchange.com/users/13738/user2626169?tab=questions): This site is intended for actual questions travelers have, not every hypothetical border crossing possibility. Do you actually know a French person in Kazakhstan with a motorcycle, a Spanish citizen in Mongolia with a car, a Spanish citizen going to Northern Iraq with a motorcycle, and a Japanese man who wants to transit both Koreas in a fire truck?

Comment: @mts that's how epic stories start. or late bar jokes.

Answer (score 2):

[Move One](https://www.moveoneinc.com/blog/moving/enmoving-iraq-2/) from four years ago has:

> **B. Import of Vehicles**
>
> It is not allowed for individuals to import vehicles for personal use
>   on a temporary regime, customs clearance must be done on a permanent
>   basis. Vehicles for company use can be imported on a temporary as well
>   as on a permanent basis.
>
> Vehicles (non-armoured) brought into the country must be manufactured
>   in 2010 or later, otherwise import will not be allowed. Apart from the
>   paperwork required for customs clearance of normal household goods,
>   the following documents are needed for import customs clearance of a
>   vehicle:
>
> ```
> Ownership paperwork
> Certificate of title
> Proforma invoice
> Passport copy
> Copy of BOL
> In case of vehicle import for a company, approval from Ministry of Interior as well as 
>  from regional customs office will be required
> ```
>
> Payment of 8-10% duties and taxes is applicable if no diplomatic
>   protocol is received from consignee’s Embassy. Amount of duties and
>   taxes is calculated based on the declared customs value indicated on
>   the proforma invoice.

The same page provides details regarding Import of Household Goods (HHG) and cautions:

> Import procedure in Iraq is very time consuming and is not always running efficiently. Even the diplomatic customs clearance can take two weeks or longer.
>
> Please note that due to the current situation in Iraq regulations
>   change daily and rules in use in certain parts of the country may
>   differ from the ones described above.